# Who was Did Paul Maud-Dib's Jihad conducted against and why did it happen?

Tags: dune

Between Dune and Dune Messiah, Paul Maud-Dib's Fremen armies swept across the galaxy in a bloody Jihad.

What I don't understand is who this Jihad was raged against.  The key Harkonnen leaders were all dead, House Atreides was aligned with House Corrino through the wedding of Paul to Irulan.

So who was it that the Jihad was raged against, and why did the Fremen commit such a bloody atrocity?  What about their religion and culture demanded such a war (as I understand it the Lisan-al-Gaib prophesy and Liet's vision for Arakkis did not necessitate galactic war)?

I am not interested in answers from the Dune movie.

Comment: It was waged against ***everyone***.

Comment: Then what was the point of marrying Irulan?  The books said that the Jihad was Paul's way of avoiding the Golden Path.

Comment: Also, if that is the answer, throw in a few quotes and I'll accept it as answer.

Comment: to make humanity so sick of despotism that they would literally flee to all corners of the galaxy to get away from it. The Golden Path required humanity to first become like a coiled spring that would later explode, ejecting humanity to every square inch of the universe in such numbers that they could never be endangered again as a species.--- from the other answer

Comment: The quote from Dune is *"“Don’t be facetious, girl! You know as well as I do what forces surround us. **We’ve a three-point civilization: the Imperial Household balanced against the Federated Great Houses of the Landsraad,** and between them, the Guild with its damnable monopoly on interstellar transport.*". By the end of book 3, all of the great houses are basically neutered or destroyed. Their nukes were taken away from them (by force) and their armies were routed. The Empire is remade as a 'single point' civilisation with Paul at its head, no great houses and a totally subservient guild.